# getting similarity score from postgres query

Tags: postgresql, embedding

have a postgre query like this

```
cursor.execute(
    "SELECT text FROM tbl_embeddings ORDER BY embedding <=> %s::vector LIMIT 1;",
    (get_embedding(txt),),
)
```

I have some embedding vectors stored in postgre and here I am doing a query to do a cosine similarity search. how can I get the similarity score from the query?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

To get the similarity score from your PostgreSQL query when performing a cosine similarity search, you can use the pg_similarity extension, which provides cosine similarity functions. You need to install this extension and use its functions in your query.install the pg_similarity extension if you haven't already then modify your query like this:

```
cursor.execute(
    """
    SELECT
        text,
        COS_TEXT(text_vector, %s::vector) AS similarity_score
    FROM
        tbl_embeddings
    ORDER BY
        text_vector <=> %s::vector
    LIMIT 1;
    """,
    (get_embedding(txt), get_embedding(txt)),
)
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: after looking at your answer, I felt silly because I already have it in my queries. I am using Azure Postgre Database Flexible Server, here is the ```query.cursor.execute(
    "SELECT text, embedding <=> %s::vector as similarity_score FROM tbl_embeddings ORDER BY embedding <=> %s::vector LIMIT 1;",
    (get_embedding(txt),get_embedding(txt),),
)```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this worked for me and hopefully will help others to see what worked:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT text, embedding <=> %s::vector as similarity_score FROM tbl_embeddings ORDER BY embedding <=> %s::vector LIMIT 3;",     (input_embedding[0],input_embedding[0],), )
```

Where input_embedding[0] is my list of embeddings I generated for searching against the database, so here I am doing a search on the first embedding (index 0). I do get some results such as:

[('horse', 0.0),
('pony', 0.2244878313977564),
('horse acessories', 0.2259605392241033)]

As a follow up question though, what do they mean? Is it the smaller the score the better? Is 0 a perfect match score? I can't seem to find any documentation for pgvector vector databases

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).